# reach php array elements in json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I return an array of array from php to json

here's php array

```
$cities = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $cityRow= array('cityNo'=>$row['city_no'], 'cityName'=>$row['city_name']);
    $cities[]=$cityRow;
}   
echo json_encode($cities);
```

Here's the json

```
$.getJSON("controllers/Customer.controller.php",param,function(result){
    // what should I write here to reach the array elements??
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can iterate over the object using [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$.getJSON("controllers/Customer.controller.php", param, function(json){

    // loop over each object in the array
    // 'i' is the index of the object within the array
    // 'val' (or this) is the actual object at that offset
    $.each(json, function(i, val) {
        console.log(val.cityNo); // same as this.cityNo
        console.log(val.cityName); // same as this.cityName
    });
});
```

Comment: I make alert instead of consol,cz I use notpad++, but It doesn't alert with city name and city no, even result(cities names and nos) are shown in the firebug consol as a response for the request !

Comment: Maybe the JSON is invalid? Can you paste it into www.jsonlint.com and check it for errors? Here's a little demo just to demonstrate that the above works: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/8uMnm/

Comment: @Alaa - "all strings, whether they are properties or values, must be enclosed in double quotes". http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Can u tell me what is the IDE that has a consol that shows javascript result?

Comment: @Alaa - You just need FireFox or Chrome (there are others) but I use those ones mainly. Chrome has a built-in 'inspector' and firefox has the firebug plugin (www.getfirebug.com). I think you'll find those to be life-savers.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [documentation on jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) you can do

```
$.getJSON("controllers/Customer.controller.php",param,function(result){
    alert(result.cityNo);
    alert(result.cityName);
});
```

Comment: It's an array of objects, not a single object, so some sort of a loop is required.